# Lookup and merge data

Tags: excel, vba

Using below code which has 2 condition to look up the data and then join the multiple result based on conditions.

The issue at hand is that all data is being displayed rather than only the filtered data when specific cell `$K$2` is not empty, in both condition all data is being displayed by code. Currently, it is unclear where the code is experiencing difficulties and why it is not functioning as intended.

**1st** condition is to show all data if specific cell `$K$2` is empty.
**2nd** if specific cell `$K$2` is not empty then show filtered data based on that value.

```
=@IF(G7="", "", Merged_Lookup_Concat(G7, Table1[Date and time], $K$2, Table1[Title], Table1[Time and Title]))
```

...

```
Function Merged_Lookup_Concat(SearchDate As String, _
                               SDate As Range, SearchValue As String, _
                               SValue As Range, ReturnCol As Range, Optional K2Value As String) As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim result As String
    Dim j As Integer
    j = 0

    If K2Value <> "" Then
 For i = 1 To SDate.Cells.CountLarge
    Debug.Print "SearchValue: " & SearchValue
    Debug.Print "SValue: " & SValue.Cells(i).value
    If Int(SDate.Cells(i).value) = SearchDate Then
        If SValue.Cells(i).value = SearchValue Or SValue.Cells(i).value = "" Then
            If j >= 5 Then
                result = result & "...more..."
                Exit For
            End If
            result = result & Left(ReturnCol.Cells(i).value, 25) & vbNewLine
            j = j + 1
        End If
    End If
Next i
    Else
        For i = 1 To SDate.Cells.CountLarge
            If Int(SDate.Cells(i)) = SearchDate Then
                If j >= 5 Then
                    result = result & "...more..."
                    Exit For
                End If
                result = result & Left(ReturnCol.Cells(i), 25) & vbNewLine
                j = j + 1
            End If
        Next i
    End If

    Merged_Lookup_Concat = Trim(result)
End Function
```

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As presented, the formula used does not include a value for the optional parameter K2Value. There are 6 parameters in the function definition, but there are only 5 parameters in the function call:

=@IF(G7="", "", Merged_Lookup_Concat(G7, Table1[Date and time], $K$2, Table1[Title], Table1[Time and Title]))

Function Merged_Lookup_Concat(SearchDate As String, _
SDate As Range, SearchValue As String, _
SValue As Range, ReturnCol As Range, Optional K2Value As String) As String

The optional parameter K2Value is not included in the function call, so it will always contain it's default value of a nullstring. Then, since the K2Value paramater is always equal to "", regardless of what is in the K2 cell, the first half of the function is never used, only the 2nd half, which filters on Search Date only and ignores Search Value.

The value of the K2 cell is passed into the SearchValue parameter, so it is this parameter that needs to be checked to determine whether there is a value in K2.

I think the line:

```
If K2Value <> "" Then
```

just needs to be replaced with

```
If SearchValue <> "" Then
```

And there's no need for the optional K2Value parameter in the function definition.

Answer (score 1):

- Chage date comparation in `If` condition clause
- ***Note:*** The goal of `Optional K2Value` is not mentioned in your post. So two sections in `If K2Value <> "" Then [section 1] Else [section 2]`  are same.

```vb
Function Merged_Lookup_Concat(SearchDate As String, SDate As Range, SearchValue As String, SValue As Range, ReturnCol As Range, Optional K2Value As String) As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim result As String
    Dim j As Integer
    j = 0
    If K2Value <> "" Then
        For i = 1 To SDate.Cells.CountLarge
            Debug.Print "SearchValue: " & SearchValue
            Debug.Print "SValue: " & SValue.Cells(i).Value
            If CLng(SDate.Cells(i)) = CLng(CDate(SearchDate)) Then
                If Len(SearchValue) = 0 Or SValue.Cells(i) = SearchValue Then
                    If j >= 5 Then
                        result = result & "...more..."
                        Exit For
                    End If
                    result = result & Left(ReturnCol.Cells(i).Value, 25) & vbNewLine
                    j = j + 1
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    Else
        For i = 1 To SDate.Cells.CountLarge
            If CLng(SDate.Cells(i)) = CLng(CDate(SearchDate)) Then
                If Len(SearchValue) = 0 Or SValue.Cells(i) = SearchValue Then
                    If j >= 5 Then
                        result = result & "...more..."
                        Exit For
                    End If
                    result = result & Left(ReturnCol.Cells(i), 25) & vbNewLine
                    j = j + 1
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End If
    Merged_Lookup_Concat = Trim(result)
End Function
```

Comment: Hey @taller thank you for posting an answer. Now in both case its result is empty i think its because `K2value` which is actually `SearchValue As String`

Comment: I don't think `K2value` is used in your formula. `Merged_Lookup_Concat(G7, Table1[Date and time], $K$2, Table1[Title], Table1[Time and Title])`

Comment: I apologize for the delayed response. I wanted to clarify that within the code, the line `If K2Value <> ""` Then` indicates that a value must be present in order for the condition to be met. In this scenario, the `$K$2` cell determines whether a value should be present or if the cell should be left empty in order to run the code for both condition. So what i am saying is `$K$2` cell should have that condition like `If $K$2 <> "" ` instead of `K2Value `

Answer (score 0):

Optional Arguments should have a default value:

```
Function Merged_Lookup_Concat(SearchDate As String, _
                               SDate As Range, SearchValue As String, _
                               SValue As Range, ReturnCol As Range, Optional K2Value As String = "") As String
```

If not, you have to check IsMissing for the argument like:

```
 If IsMissing(K2Value) Then
```

Comment: This will not work - `IsMissing` doesn't work for simple data types, only for Variants. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ismissing-function. Instead, you can check for `If K2Value="" Then` - that will work even if there is no default value as the empty string is the default for strings in VBA. But of course it's best practise to specify the default value explicitly

Comment: UUps - should test first before writing. So used not to do optional without default from .net that I remembered only the IsMissing but not, the variant thing :-(
Thanks for correction.